# Recursive inclusion exclusion principle

Tags: probability, inclusion-exclusion, recursive-algorithms

The inclusion exclusion principle is as follows:

$P\Bigl(\bigcup_{i=1}^n E_i\Bigr) = \sum_{i\le n} P(E_i) - \sum_{i_1<i_2}P(E_{i_1}\cap E_{i_2})+\sum_{i_1<i_2<i_3}P(E_{i_1}\cap E_{i_2}\cap E_{i_3}) \dots$

is there any way to write this equation recursively?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Yes***

based on [Reduced Recursive Inclusion-exclusion Principle for the probability of union events](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/7058590)

let

$π(Y_1, Y_2,...,Y_n) ≡ Pr(Y_1∪Y_2∪···∪ Y_n)$

be the function of probability of union events. According to the equivalent rearrangement, we have the following definition of recursive inclusion-exclusion principle:

$\pi(\emptyset) = 0$

$π(A_1) = Pr(A_1)$, for $n = 1$

$π(A_1, A_2,...,A_n) = \sum_{i=1}^n{Pr(A_i)−π(A_1 ∩ A_i, A_2 ∩ A_i,...,A_{i−1} ∩ A_i)}$, for $n > 1$

where $π(•)$ is a recursive function

Comment: What do you mean by $π(A_1 ∩ A_i, A_2 ∩ A_i,...,A_{i−1} ∩ A_i)$ when $i=1$?  Is that like $\pi(\emptyset) = 0$ ?

Comment: Yes, you are right, we have to consider this as well

Comment: I can see that the formula is correct.  It is effectively saying "for each new part added, subtract the part that is already counted."  Can you briefly say what advantage this has over the usual formula?

Comment: One of the main advantages of this recursive is that it is much easier to code than the original equation.