# Find the probability of no color in all three columns

Tags: probability, combinatorics

There are 3 columns with 7 cells each one. Each cell can be painted independently with one of eight possible colors, where each color has a different probability $P_i$ of appear
$$
P_1 = 25\% \ \ \ P_2 = 20\% \ \ \ P_3 = 15\% \ \ \ P_4 = 15\% \ \ \ P_5 = 10\% \ \ \ P_6 = 8\% \ \ \ P_7 = 5\% \ \ \ P_8 = 2\%
$$

I want to find the probability of no color in all three columns simultaneously.

**What I tried**:
This was solved it with recursion, using 5 variables: the possible colors($S$), the minimum color(after given each color a number, $i$) and the numbers of cells in each column($A, B, C$). I couldn't find a closed form so I did in a Python program (using dynamic programming), but I want to do it in a mathematical way.
$$
dp\begin{pmatrix}S \\i \\A \\B \\C\end{pmatrix}= \sum_{a=1}^A \sum_{b=1}^B \sum_{c=1}^C \binom{A}{a} \binom{B}{b}  \binom{C}{c}   \frac{ \tilde{P}_i^{a+b+c} }{(1 - \tilde{P}_i)^{a-A+b-B+c-C}} [1 - \sum_{\substack{k<i \\ k \in S}} dp\begin{pmatrix}S-\{ i \} \\k \\A - a \\B - b \\C - c\end{pmatrix}]
$$
$$
\tilde{P}_i = \frac{P_i}{\sum_{j \in S}{P_j}}
$$
**Generalization**:
Even if this question seems too specific, I want to generalize this question, where there are 3 columns with $n$ cells each one and each cell has $m$ possible colors (with a fixed probability each one). What I tried with recursion is too slow to calculate.

Comment: Are all 21 cells colored independently? If so, could you please add this to the question? If I understand correctly, what you don't want is that there exists a color which appears in all three columns, right?

Comment: @matija I added it to the question. Yes, I don't want a color to be in all three columns.

Comment: Thanks! You won't find a closed form and there's little hope for improvement over recursive inclusion-exclusion b/c the complexity is exponential (cf [here](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/7058590) & [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3997574/recursive-inclusion-exclusion-principle)), meaning: No matter what you come up with, it will only work for small values of $n$ and $m$. I also don't see a better partitioning scheme than the one you used. If you're interested in not too large values, I'd recommend to move from Python to C, this will give you a factor 100 boost.

Answer (score 1):

Can't be sure, but you can try inclusion and exclusion principle.

Let's $\alpha_1$ - first color exists in all $3$ columns, $\alpha_2$ - second color exists in all $3$ columns, etc.
Event $A$ - at least one color will exist in all $3$ columns.

Your probability is: $P\left(\alpha_1', \alpha_2', \ldots\right) =P(\overline A) = 1 - P(A) =  P(\bigcup_{i=1}^8 \alpha_i)$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. This should be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: Sorry, I haven't enough reputation to make a comment

Comment: @PavelStivens I tried inclusion-exclusion, but I need the following value: Given a column what is the probability that exists some colors (for example 1, 3 and 4). To solve that I used inclusion and exclusion again. Do you know any other way to calculate this?